# What does the phrase "followed to solicit" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The president of a large Japanese real estate firm was another. He'd sent Eisman his company's financial statements and then **followed**, with an interpreter, to solicit Eisman's investment. "You don't even own stock in your company," said Eisman, after the typically elaborate Japanese businessman introductions.-*The Big Short* by Michael Lewis

What does it mean "followed to solicit" in this sentence?

Comment: It also doesn't seem to have object to it's verb "followed"

Comment: "went on to solicit Eisman's investment" or "followed this by soliciting Eisman's investment" sound more natural. That doesn't mean Lewis is wrong but I can't find this use of follow in any dictionary.

Comment: oh, okay "went on" means he visited Eisman and what does it mean "followed this" ?

Comment: It means he sent Eisman statements and then solicited Eisman's investment. "follow" means to go after something else.